# Adding a form to an admin model gives a many-to-many error - Why is this form causing this issue

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to customize the add button of a model in the admin interface. In order to do that I wrote an admin model for this model and tried to override the `add_view` definition. However I am getting the error

```
"<modelStudent: Student:>" needs to have a value for field "modelstudent" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

This is my model

```
class modelStudent(models.Model):
    user             = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    school           = models.ForeignKey(modelSchool)
    first_name       = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=False)
```

and this is the admin Model for that model

```
class modelStudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = adminStudentForm


    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(modelStudentAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)

        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        else:
            schoolInstance = modelSchool.objects.get(user=request.user)
            qs = modelStudent.objects.filter(school=schoolInstance)
            return qs


    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
           return super(modelStudentAdmin,self).add_view(request,form_url,extra_context)

        elif request.method == 'POST':
            form = UploadFileForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                email = form.cleaned_data["send_email"]
                handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'],request)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/')
        else:
            form = UploadFileForm()
        return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

I believe this issue is because of the form assignment `form = adminStudentForm` 
Here is the adminStudentForm

```
class adminStudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = modelStudent
        fields = '__all__'

    patients = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=modelPatient.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(adminStudentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['patients'].initial = self.instance.modelpatient_set.all()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            instance = super(adminStudentForm, self).save(commit=False)
            patients_qset = self.cleaned_data['patients']
            for pqset in patients_qset:
                pqset.student.add(instance)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            raise
        return instance
```

Here is the modelPatient

```
    class modelPatient(models.Model):
            student            = models.ManyToManyField(modelStudent,null=True,default=None,blank=True)
            patient_name       = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=False) 
        patient_age        = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Why does adding the form here cause the issue ? Any idea on how I can resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you put this under the modelStudent? Not sure, but worth a try...

```
def __str__(self):
    return(self.user)
```